# Phpmyadmin sql command isn't working, what is wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to setup a table in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE products(
  id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR(255),
  info TEXT,
  price DOUBLE(10)
);
```

and got the error #1064, but I think there is no error in my SQL syntax.

Comment: Double datatype requires precision eg(10,2)

Comment: Is DOUBLE(10) a valid data type?

Comment: 'MySQL permits a nonstandard syntax: FLOAT(M,D) or REAL(M,D) or DOUBLE PRECISION(M,D). Here, (M,D) means than values can be stored with up to M digits in total, of which D digits may be after the decimal point. ' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html

Answer (score 0):

This is due to Wrong Datatype specification while creating Table. 
You can use FLOAT(10) if required, if you want to use Double, you have to mention the precision value as DOUBLE(10,0).